# Is this clever infinite recursion breaking technique within an object actually possible?

Tags: python, object, recursion, dependencies

The object: A Node, which has a value and an optional reference to another Node. Classes that inherit from Node may have more complex references to other Nodes, and handling circular references will prove vital to my personal use case later on.

For this question I’ll show a simplified version of the code, which just checks if it reaches the original object (with the desired check commented out):

```
class Node:
    '''A basic node for dependency mapping. Bundles another type with a reference.'''
    def __init__(self, val = None, ref = None):
        self.ref = ref
        self.val = val

    def __getattribute__(self, name, source = None):
        #While iterating through multiple nodes, throws 
        #an error if the original node is reached. 

        #if self in source:
        if self is source:
            raise AttributeError("Circular dependency detected in getattr()")
        elif name == "ref":
            #Somehow pass the source node into the next node's getattr() call.
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

In theory, if the elif part of getattribute could work, I could handle the raised exception on a case by case basis depending on the function, and not have to code the checks in as many places.

Is it even possible to pass additional parameters to built in functions in Python? And are there better ways to code the error being thrown?

Comment: I don't think just passing the first node around is sufficient to detect cycles. Suppose node A points to node B, and B points to C, and C points to B. If you try to traverse this graph, you'll traverse A once, then cycle through B and C forever, and any cycle-breaking code that's waiting to see A again will never execute.

Comment: I recognized that, hence the commented line that would instead take a list or set with all the previous nodes in it.

Comment: A list of all previous nodes is a promising approach... IIRC, that's how Python ensures that `a = []; a.append(a); print(a)` prints `[[...]]` instead of looping forever. It can get a bit expensive, though, since list membership testing is O(N) and you may be doing it up to N times, for a total of O(N^2). Set membership testing is cheaper, but it may or may not be difficult to make your nodes implement the required "hashable" interface.

Comment: Equals was easy enough, it just checks for the same object type and value. But I wasn’t quite sure on how to handle hash function implementation, but I think I came up with a simple, if perhaps a little inefficient, way to do so that works for my purposes: return hash(hash(self.val)+hash(object.__hash__(self)))

Comment: What I feel I want to do with the code in the elif block is call the reference node’s getattribute function with the additional source parameter and the next name Python is looking to call. Thing is, I’m not sure how to pass the next name value in, or if it might mess stuff up. But if there is a way, it’d be brilliant for my needs.